# Do the following binary vectors span $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, linear-algebra, matrices, divisors-multiples, vector-spaces

**Defining the binary vectors**

Let an ordered triple of natural numbers $(r, d, n)$ such that $0 \leq r < d \leq n$ be given.

Consider the binary vector $v_{(r,d,n)} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that for all $i \in \{0\} \cup [n-1]$:
\begin{align*}
(v_{(r,d,n)})_i = 1 & \quad\text{if $i \equiv r \mod d$} \\
(v_{(r,d,n)})_i = 0 & \quad\text{otherwise.}
\end{align*}

In other words, $r$ is the remainder, $d$ is the divisor, and $n$ is the dimension.

**An example vector**

Let's take $r = 1$, $d = 3$, and $n = 14$.  In this case, we have:

$$
v_{(1,3,14)} = (0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1).
$$

**Defining the subspaces**

Let an ordered pair of natural numbers $(m, n)$ such that $m \leq n$ be given.

Consider the subspace $V_{(m,n)} \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ given by
$$
V_{(m,n)} = \operatorname{span} \{ v_{(r, d, n)} \; \vert \; 0 \leq r < d \leq m \}.
$$
In other words, $m$ is a bound for the divisor.

**My Question**

Let a natural number $n$ be given.

Consider the function $k(n)$ given by:
$$
k(n) \mathrel{:=} \min \{ m \; \vert \; V_{(m,n)} = \mathbb{R}^n \}.
$$

Without much effort, it can be shown that $k(n) \leq n$ and $k(n) = \Omega(\sqrt{n})$.

Can we prove asymptotically tighter bounds on $k(n)$?  My intuition is that $k(n) = O(\sqrt{n} \cdot \log(n))$.

**Update 1**

The problem has be solved thanks to @Ilya Bogdanov.

Below I added a snippet of Octave code in case anyone is interested in checking on smaller values of $n$.

As requested, for the $n = 30$ case, we have $k(30) = 10$.

```
% Parameters
n = 30
m = 10

% Compute number of rows & cols
rows = (m + 1) * m / 2
cols = n

% Construct matrix
M = zeros(rows, cols);
count = 1;
for d = 1:m
  for r = 0:(d-1)
    for c = 1:cols
      if r == mod(c-1, d)
        M(count, c) = 1;
      end
    end
    count += 1;
  end
end

% Print matrix
M

% Print rank
rankOfM = rank(M)
```

**Update 2**

Below is a table of values for $k(n)$ when $1 \leq n \leq 50$.

```
| n  | k(n) |
-------------
| 1  |  1   |
| 2  |  2   |
| 3  |  3   |
| 4  |  3   |
| 5  |  4   |
| 6  |  4   |
| 7  |  5   |
| 8  |  5   |
| 9  |  5   |
| 10 |  5   |
| 11 |  6   |
| 12 |  6   |
| 13 |  7   |
| 14 |  7   |
| 15 |  7   |
| 16 |  7   |
| 17 |  7   |
| 18 |  7   |
| 19 |  8   |
| 20 |  8   |
| 21 |  8   |
| 22 |  8   |
| 23 |  9   |
| 24 |  9   |
| 25 |  9   |
| 26 |  9   |
| 27 |  9   |
| 28 |  9   |
| 29 |  10  |
| 30 |  10  |
| 31 |  10  |
| 32 |  10  |
| 33 |  11  |
| 34 |  11  |
| 35 |  11  |
| 36 |  11  |
| 37 |  11  |
| 38 |  11  |
| 39 |  11  |
| 40 |  11  |
| 41 |  11  |
| 42 |  11  |
| 43 |  12  |
| 44 |  12  |
| 45 |  12  |
| 46 |  12  |
| 47 |  13  |
| 48 |  13  |
| 49 |  13  |
| 50 |  13  |
```

Comment: I did write some code in Octave to try out some smaller cases when $n < 500$.  The experiment seemed to be inconclusive.  But, I still think it should be close to $\sqrt{n}$.

Comment: I did a related post a couple weeks ago and @mathworker21's answer and discussion led me to the current question.  The old post asked some questions related to when the divisor is a prime number and we obtained some small results:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3360599/binary-vectors-defined-by-remainders-modulo-prime-numbers-what-is-the-dimension

Comment: One thing to note is that if $d_1$ divides $d_2$, then all vectors with $d_1$ as the divisor can be represented as a linear combination of vectors that have $d_2$ as the divisor.  As a result, the prime number case seems to possibly be different.

Comment: This problem came up from a computer science theory problem that I have been working on for some time.  Essentially, I am trying to characterize a bit string using the simplest set of equations as possible.  The "simple" equations have a very specialized form that just so happens to be similar to the form of these vectors.

Comment: It would help to post an example of the pairs $(r,d)$ that give the minimal result, e.g. for $n=30$.

Comment: @MattF. Thank you for the comment!  I will try to post some results from the experiment that I ran in a few days.  I will include some values for $k(n)$ when $n \leq 100$.  :)

Comment: Display math `$$ $$` works fine in MathJax; there's no need to abuse the formatting to simulate it.

Comment: @LSpice Thank you!  I should have used align for defining the vectors when I originally wrote it.  It looks better now!

Comment: @MattF. Hi again!  I happened to get a chance to check today.  We have k(30) = 10.  I added the Octave code above.  If you plug in m = 9, you will see that the rank is only 28, but when m = 10, the rank is 30.

Comment: @mathworker21 Thank you very much for the update!  Please do share the link if you're able to.  Hope that you're having a nice weekend.  :)

Comment: @mathworker21 I just found the link: https://arxiv.org/abs/2007.12097

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let $v_{r,d}$ be an *infinite* sequence defined in the same way, and let $V_m$ be the span of all corresponding sequences with $d\leq m$.

For a fixed $d$, the linear span of all $v_{r,d}$ is the set of all linear recurrences with characteristic polynomial
$$
  x^d-1=\prod_{k\mid d} \Phi_k(x),
$$
where $\Phi_k$ is the $k$th cyclotomic polynomial. Therefore, $V_{m}$ is the set of all linear recurrences with characteristic polynomial
$$
  P_m(x)= \mathop{\mathrm{lcm}}\left\{x^d-1\colon d\leq m\right\}= \prod_{k\leq m} \Phi_k(x).
$$
Thus, whenever $ \deg P_m\geq n$, the sequences from $V_m$ may have arbitrary first $n$ terms, so $V_{m,n}=\mathbb R^n$. Conversely, if $\deg P_m<n$, the  set $V_{m,n}$ is not the whole space due to dimension reasons.

The inequality rewrites as
$$
  S_m=  \sum_{k\leq m}\varphi(k)\geq n.
$$
The asymptotics of $S_m$ is known (see, e.g., https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farey_sequence) and is $S_m\sim3m^2/\pi^2$ (this can be easily derived from the number of coprime pairs of positive integers not exceeding $m$). Hence, the correct order is indeed $k(n)\sim \pi \sqrt{n/3}$.

Comment: The asymptotics for the case when $d$ should be prime (or with other restrictions imposed on $d$) might be obtained similarly

Comment: This is awesome!  It took me a couple hours to work out all of the details as I wasn't very familiar with all of these concepts.  Thank you so much.  :)

Comment: So in general, it sounds like the following (or something quite similar) holds.  If $R_1$ and $R_2$ are linear recurrences with (1) characteristic polynomials $p_1$ and $p_2$ and (2) solution sets $S_1$ and $S_2$, respectively, then there exists a linear recurrence $R_3$ with characteristic polynomial $lcm\{p_1,p_2\}$ and solution set $S_1 + S_2$.  Further, $R_3$ is unique with respect to the characteristic polynomial as well as the solution set.  Note: by a linear congruence, I mean just the equation excluding initial conditions.

Comment: Great answer. I was thinking along those lines myself.

Comment: Yes, for the variation of the question with only prime divisors, we should have $k(n) = \Theta(\sqrt{n \log n})$.

Comment: If you're interested, I would be happy to share what led me to this problem.  Please feel free to contact me.  Thanks again!  :)

Comment: I said linear congruence in the "note" part of my comment above, but meant to say linear recurrence.

Comment: @MichaelWehar idk why you're defining "linear recurrence" differently from Ilya. It's very clear that Ilya defined it as just an infinite sequence; I think things will be easier if you stuck with his definition. Instead of your comment talking about solution sets: He is just using the fact that the span of the set of all linear recurrences with characteristic polynomial $P_1$ and the set of all linear recurrences with characteristic polynomial $P_2$ is the set of all linear recurrences with characteristic polynomial $lcm(P_1,P_2)$.

Comment: @MichaelWehar I think his solution is actually simple, but the wording confused me at first and your comments about needing to look up a lot of stuff about linear recurrences made me think the solution actually used a lot of stuff. But I am pretty sure it just uses the thing I mentioned in my previous comment.

Comment: @mathworker21 Thank you for the comment!  Maybe I over complicated it as you suggested.  Hope to come back to this next week.  :)

Comment: @mathworker21 Sorry for my delayed reply!  Yes, you need "the fact that the span of the set of all linear recurrences with characteristic polynomial P1 and the set of all linear recurrences with characteristic polynomial P2 is the set of all linear recurrences with characteristic polynomial lcm(P1,P2)".  I wanted to verify this claim so it took me a bit of work and I didn't post the proof online.  To prove it, I had to relate "linear recurrences" with "linear recurrence equations" and their solution sets.

Comment: @mathworker21 Maybe I didn't explain that very well the first time.  If you happen to have a simple argument that doesn't consider "linear recurrence equations" or a book that canonically proves this, please let me know.  It is quite possible that there is a simple proof that I missed.  Thank you!

Comment: @MichaelWehar well, the definition of characteristic polynomial is based on linear recurrence equations, so I'm not exactly sure what you mean. you should have posted your proof of it here. I'll write down a proof later if you want. Also, I hope you are safe and doing well :)

Comment: @mathworker21 Thank you for the follow-up!  This is good.  Now, I think that we're almost on the same page.  Let me try to explain further.  So for now on-wards, by linear recurrence equation, we mean an equation following the standard format that describes a set of infinite sequences.  Each linear recurrence equation is associated with a characteristic polynomial and a non-recursive formula which we refer to as its solution formula.

Comment: @mathworker21 Given two linear recurrence equations $E_1$ and $E_2$, we can consider the associated characteristic polynomials $p_1$ and $p_2$ and solution formulas $f_1$ and $f_2$.  We can construct a linear recurrence equation $E_3$ whose characteristic polynomial is $lcm\{p_1, p_2\}$.  If you carefully look at the known possible formats for solution formulas, we can actually see that the solution formula for $E_3$ is roughly $f_1 + f_2$.  As a result, $E_3$'s set of infinite sequences is actually the span of infinite sequences from $E_1$ and $E_2$.

Comment: @mathworker21 In other words, I couldn't show that $E_3$'s set of infinite sequences was the span of infinite sequences from $E_1$ and $E_2$ directly.  There probably is a direct method for doing this that I overlooked.  Instead, I had to look at the known non-recursive solution formulas (based on the classic results for solving linear recurrences) for $E_1$, $E_2$, and $E_3$.

Comment: @MichaelWehar what are $f_1,f_2$? Are they sets of solutions? There are initial conditions..

Comment: @mathworker21 I believe that for the equation $x_n = x_{n-1} + x_{n-2}$ we get the formula $-3n - 10 + \alpha_1 (\frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2})^n + \alpha_2 (\frac{1 - \sqrt{5}}{2})^n$.  There is a bijective association between initial conditions and values for $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$.

Comment: @mathworker21 Note: This example is associated with the Fibonacci sequence.  There is a general format for the solution formulas that is related to the characteristic polynomial of the linear recurrence equation.

Comment: @MichaelWehar thanks! I'm a bit confused why your purported proof would not be direct, since $E_3$ is defined by $lcm(p_1,p_2)$, so you have to use $lcm(p_1,p_2)$ in a proof that $E_3$'s set of infinite sequences was the span of the infinite sequences from $E_1$ and $E_2$.

Comment: @mathworker21 Sorry, I said direct, but I meant that I suspect you can prove it without investigating the solution formulas of $E_1$, $E_2$, and $E_3$.

Comment: @MichaelWehar thanks a lot

Comment: @mathworker21 Thank you for being interested in this and for continuing to exchange comments about this.  :)